# Prove that the set $\{((p\to q)\lor r),(p\lor(q\lor s))\}$ is satisfiable?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Am I using the correct logic in my proof below?

Rewriting the first element in the set using Logical equivalence involving Conditional statement yields: $(\neg p\lor q)\lor r$ – this can be further rewritten to:
$\neg p\lor (q \lor r)$ by applying the commutative and associate laws.

Let $A=(q\lor r)$

Let $B=(q\lor s)$

The above set can be considered satisfiable if $\neg p\lor A,p\lor B \vDash_{taut} (A\lor B)$

1. Let $v(\neg p \lor A)=v(p\lor B)=t$

Case 1: $v(p)=t$: by (1), $v(A)=t$. But then $v(A\lor B)$=t.

Case 2: $v(p)=f$: by (1), $v(B)=t$. But then $v(A\lor B)=t$

QED

Comment: It would be easier to just observe that both disjunctions would be satisfied if the common disjunct, $q$, were true.

Comment: I'm trying to apply stuff I've read, so I'm not sure if I'm over complicating it, but would this make sense to prove? Let $A=(p\to q)\lor r,B=p\lor (q\lor s)$ The set is satisfiable if $A,B\vDash_{taut} (A\land B)$ then prove $v(A)=t, v(B)=t$ when $v(q)=t$.

Answer (score 1):

Knowing the truth table of ( X v Y) one can see that :

(1) R being true is a sufficient condition for ( P-->Q) v R to be true.

(2) P being true is a sufficient condition for P v ( Q v S) to be true.

So any interpretation assigning the truth value " true" to R and to P makes the 2 formulas true at the same time , for example :

P --> true

Q --> false

R --> true

S --> false

So there is at least one interpretation in which both formulas are true at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you're doing is proving that if the original pair of formulas, $(p\to q)\lor r$ and $p\lor(q\lor s)$, are (simultaneously) satisfied, then so is the *single* formula $A\lor B$.  But that's not what you are asked to do. In short, you seem to be *assuming* the *requested* conclusion, and obtaining some other, unrequested conclusion.

All you need to do, instead, is show that some assignment of true/false values to $p$, $q$, $r$, and $s$ make the two formulas $(p\to q)\lor r$ and $p\lor(q\lor s)$ both true. As Graham Kemp notes in comments below the OP, setting $q$'s value to true makes both formulas true, regardless of the values for $p$, $r$, and $s$. Alternatively, setting the values of both $r$ and $s$ to true does the trick as well. Indeed, the only assignments for $(p,q,r,s)$ that do *not* satisfy the two formulas are $(t,f,f,f)$ and $(f,f,f,f)$, since, as you found, their conjunction is tautologically equivalent to $A\lor B=(q\lor r)\lor(q\lor s)=q\lor r\lor s$.